# Importing modules from different directory in python

Tags: python

This is the file structure

```
app.py
other_repo >
   helpers.py
   logic.py¨
   ...
```

`app.py` uses code from different modules under `other_repo`. `other_repo` is my own private github repo that I've pulled in the work dir. `other_repo > logic.py` has dependencies to `other_repo > helpers.py`:

```
# other_repo > helpers.py
def get_value() -> int:
    return 5
```

```
# other_repo > logic.py
import helpers

def multiply_value(x: int) -> int:
    value = helpers.get_value()
    return x * value
```

```
# app.py
import other_repo.logic as logic

multiplied_value = logic.multiply_value(10)
print(f'Multiplied value is {multiplied_value})
# Multiplied value is 50
```

When I run `app.py` I get an error in `\other_repo\logic.py` for `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'`.

If in `logic.py` I change the import to `import unpoco.helpers` instead of `import helpers` it works, but every time I pull updates to that repo it would update the imports back to the original one.

Comment: I would suggest installing the `other_repo` with `pip install -e other_repo` instead of importing from a path

Comment: @MatteoZanoni other_repo is my own repo that I've pulled from github, that's why it's in a path. Updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: You could try adding the path to the other repo first. `sys.path.append("/other/repo/path")` and then importing the logic as `import other_repo.logic as logic`

Comment: @Wavy this doesn't work - the issue is that `logic.py` is not able to find the file `helpers.py` unless the import statement within `logic.py` is changed to `import other_repo.helpers as helpers`, even though they are in the same dir (`other_repo`)